# Will Datalab automatically provision the already existing computation engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-datalab

I have already created a computation engine with 16 GB RAM and 8 Core processor. When I start a datalab instance does this run on the already configured computation engine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created the above VM via [create command](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/reference/command-line/create) `$ gcloud create NAME`,  then you should be able to see this Datalab instance by running the [list command](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/reference/command-line/list) `$ datalab list`.

If it's in your datalab list, then you should be able to use the [connect command](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/reference/command-line/connect) `$ datalab connect NAME` to connect to that instance.